# Turing completeness of Bitcoin Script

Tags: transactions, script, development, alternatives, turing-completeness

For me, scripts are one of the most interesting features of Bitcoin. They provide possibilities which have no equivalent in classical currencies. However, the [wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script) states

> It is purposefully not Turing-complete, with no loops.

1. What's the rationale behind this decision?
2. Are there any proposals for useful contracts which would only be possible in a Turing complete script implementation?
3. Are there any alternative crypto currencies with Turing complete scripts? If so, how do they solve the problems from 1?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If scripts were Turing-complete, you could construct a fairly short script that took an extremely long time to run (a la the [Busy Beaver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver)) or contained an infinite loop.  This would tend to result in a denial of service against everyone on the network, when they tried to verify the transaction.

And there would be no general way to tell whether a script would loop infinitely or would eventually finish: that's the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

One could try to avoid this by including some sort of cutoff on how long a client will spend verifying a transaction, but it would have to be done very carefully so as to be consistent across all clients: if some accept it and others don't, the block chain will fork.

It seems simpler to avoid the situation all together.

Comment: If there was a limit, it would be better to have a limit on how many instructions could be executed rather than time spent, to ensure consistency

Comment: @RentFree: Which essentially reduces to what we have now.  If the script you want has a loop that is guaranteed to finish within a certain number of instructions, you can unroll the loop into a straight-line script with a fixed number of instructions.  Actually, as it stands, the number of instructions you execute, the number of bytes in the script, and the fee you pay, are all approximately proportional.